# I am getting this error while creating react files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, npx

**Getting this error while creating react file ?**
C:\Users\tusha\Desktop\New folder (4)>npx create-react-app my-app
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.15.0

I have tried to re-install nodejs and delete the module by creating the module file again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your npm installation doesn't appear to be in your PATH.

Open a command prompt (windows key + R, then cmd.exe)

Update your PATH to include npm.

```bash
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm"
```

Close the terminal command prompt.

If your npm binary is in a different location, you can find it via the command prompt using

```bash
where npm
```

Comment: This appears on the screen 
C:\Users\tusha>where npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

C:\Users\tusha>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm"

WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
BUT STILL I AM NOT ABLE TO CREATE ANY REACT FILE