There is an error in code while installing react.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

I had tried to install react using visual studio code and node.js. There is an error while typing the code" npx create-react-app" and it need to be worked. The actual result need to be the installation of react, react-dom, react-scripts.

solved here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747247/i-am-getting-this-error-while-creating-react-files?rq=2

Just solve it after applying this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23258712/11330441

This answer from @stephen-taylor save the day
Open a command prompt (windows key + R, then cmd.exe)
Update your PATH to include npm.
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm"

Close the terminal command prompt.
In my case, npm was already in the path, so I had to remove it from the wrong location.
